# Laravel, Faker - generate timestamp before certain time?

Tags: php, laravel, time, limit, faker

Is there a way to generate time between, let's say, `00:00:00` and `15:00:00` in [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker)? I tried this:

```
$time   = $faker->time( 'H:i:s', '15:00:00' );
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I keep getting values between `00:00:00` and `23:59:59`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no way in Faker to achieve limit on the time part.

But forget faker for this little task:

```
 date('H:i:s', rand(1,54000)); // 00:00:00 - 15:00:00
```

Answer (score 7):

This is possible with Faker now:

```php
$faker->dateTimeBetween($startDate, $endDate);
```

`$startDate` and `$endDate` can be string or Carbon instances

Check the [date_time provider reference](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/faker.providers.date_time.html#)  for all available options.

Comment: What if we want to get timestamp to get timezone included?